# How to show that $\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}^2\right\vert=\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}\right\vert$ implies...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

How would one show that $\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}^2\right\vert=\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}\right\vert$ implies $\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}^n\right\vert=\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}\right\vert$

I know that $\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}^2\right\vert=\left\vert{\mathbb{R}}\right\vert$ implies there exists a bijection between ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ and ${\mathbb{R}}$. So for example would you argue that ${\mathbb{R}}^3={\mathbb{R}}^2\times{\mathbb{R}}$, which is in bijection with ${\mathbb{R}}\times{\mathbb{R}}$ (not sure if this follows?) which is in bijection with ${\mathbb{R}}$?

And you would proceed by induction to show this is true for all $n$?

Sorry, I know that this topic has already been covered many times on this site. It's just that I did not understand much of the discourse covered in those treatments.

Comment: Yes. For any finite $n$ this is true by induction.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to proceed.

Comment: But how do we know that ${\mathbb{R}}^2\times{\mathbb{R}}$ is in bijection with ${\mathbb{R}}\times{\mathbb{R}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\def\R{\mathbf R}\R \times \R$ is in bijection with $\R^2 \times \R$, let $f \colon \R^2 \to \R$ any bijection (which exists due to $|\R^2| = |\R|$). Now define $F \colon \R^2 \times \R \to \R \times \R$ by $F(x,y) = \bigl(f(x), y\bigr)$, $(x,y) \in \R^2 \times \R$. Then $F$ is a bijection (I'm sure, you can show why).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use an inducive approach on $n>1$ and the fact that $|A|\cdot|B|=|A\times B|$.

Comment: Welcome back! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks for saying so. :-)